# Project specific fields of embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get just one field of an specific embedded documents.

The embedded document should be filtered based on two condiditions and
then just return one field of that embedded document.

```
db.usertest.insertMany(
    [{
    "username" : "userA",
    "objects" : [
        {
        "type" : "fruit",
        "origin" : "ABC",
        "name" : "banana",
        },
        {
        "type" : "fruit",
        "origin" : "XYZ",
        "name" : "pineapple",
        },

        {
        "type" : "vegetable",
        "origin" : "XYZ",
        "name" : "carrot"
        }
    ]
    },
     {
     "username" : "userB",
     "objects" : []
     }
]
)
```

I want to find the field "username" and the field "name" of the
embedded document.

First I thought of $elemMatch, but I am stuck at the $project part and
it just returns the field "name" of all embedded documents when
$elemMatch is true.

```
db.usertest.aggregate(
    [{$match:{"objects": {"$elemMatch":{
         "type": "fruit",
         "origin": "XYZ"}}}},
     {$project: {
      "username":1,
      "objects.name":1
      }}]
).pretty()
```

Then I thought of using $filter, but it obviously just returns the
whole embedded document instead of just the field "name".

```
db.usertest.aggregate(
    [{$project: {
      "username":1,
      "name":{
          $filter: {
             input: "$objects",
             cond: { $and: [
                     { $eq: [ "$$this.type", "fruit" ] },
                  { $eq: [ "$$this.origin", "XYZ" ] }
                 ]}
          }}
      }}]
).pretty()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine multiple aggregation operators in following order:

[$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) -> [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) (to get only `name` property) -> [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) (to take first element)

```
db.usertest.aggregate(
  [{$project: {
    "username":1,
    "name": {
      $arrayElemAt: [
        {
          $map: {
            input: {
              $filter: {
                 input: "$objects",
                 cond: { $and: [
                         { $eq: [ "$$this.type", "fruit" ] },
                      { $eq: [ "$$this.origin", "XYZ" ] }
                     ]}
              }},
              as: "item",
              in: "$$item.name"
          }
        },0
      ]
    }
    }}]
).pretty()
```

Comment: Perfect! I was missing the combination of map and filter. Thanks!
Nice that your solution even allows for commenting out the arrayElemAt and then I have an array of all names given the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`no $elemMatch operator`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14876) in `$project` stage. So to use mimic similar functionality you can create `$filter` with `$arrayElemAt` with index 0 and `$let` to hold the intermediate document in a variable and output the name.

Keep the `$match` stage so you only look at documents where there is at least one matching object.

Something like

```
db.usertest.aggregate(
[{"$match":{"objects":{"$elemMatch":{"type":"fruit","origin":"XYZ"}}}},
{"$project":{
  "name":{"$let":{
    "vars":{"object":{
      "$arrayElemAt":[
        {"$filter":{
          "input":"$objects",
          "as":"o",
          "cond":{
            "$and":[
              {"$eq":["$$o.type","fruit"]},
              {"$eq":["$$o.origin","XYZ"]}
            ]
          }
        }},
        0
      ]
    }},
    "in":"$$object.name"
  }}
}}])
```